# Formating PDAL Pipeline JSON for crop filter

Tags: polygon, filter, clip, point-cloud, pdal

I'm trying to crop out a section of point cloud using PDAL pipeline filter.crop function.  Here's my JSON for pipeline:

```
{
  "pipeline":[
   {
      "type":"readers.las",
      "filename":"/data/home-output.las"
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.crop",
      "a_srs": "EPSG:4326",
      "polygon":"POLYGON ((
            -90.28151392936705 38.64088326179908,
            -90.28208792209625 38.64059415029273,
            -90.2816641330719 38.64016257587423,
            -90.28008699417114 38.640112295190406,
            -90.27978658676147 38.64051453967314,
            -90.28035521507263 38.640879071785584,
            -90.28151392936705 38.64088326179908
            ))"
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.las",
      "a_srs": "EPSG:4326",
      "filename":"/data/file-output_new.las"
    }
  ]
}
```

For some reason, it produces an empty file.  No points.  I know the coordinates are correct.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this IS formatted correctly.  My .las file from ODM needed to be reprojected into 4326 prior to this.